# Student keeps asking about attendance policy

Tags: teaching, course-evaluation

I'm offering a new grad course this semester; this is my first teaching role. One student reached out to me four months ago, asking about the attendance policy. I did not have one because I had not considered it, being new to teaching.

I told him I'd have the syllabus ready a week before the start of the semester. He reached out recently asking about the syllabus and I sent him the syllabus, which does not discuss attendance. Then he followed up with a question about attendance policy again.

As this is a grad-level topics course and is highly specialized, I don't see an attendance policy as a good fit for a grad course in general, and I don't want to enforce one. At the same time, I don't want to have it in writing that I don't care about the attendance. When it is not in the syllabus, it is not in the syllabus. I'm not too fond of the student's attitude, who keeps asking about the attendance policy four months in advance. I want to let him know that being absent is fine, but if that is his plan, this may not be the right course for him. But I don't want to book a negative teacher assessment for myself either.

**Question**:
Should I be straight with him and reply that this course may not suit him? Should I ask the department to remove him from class? Should I just answer that what is in the syllabus is what I care about?

**Update**: Following Dan's answer, I sent a short reply stating that I don't have an attendance policy. I received a reply thanking me and stating that he asked only because he will be missing 2 sessions for a conference (I hadn't even asked why). I also added a short section to my syllabus (per David's answer) stating that I don't have an attendance policy but that students should talk to me if they will miss many classes. Thanks to all for the advice.

Comment: Will it be in person only? Hybrid? Zoom only? That should be in the syllabus (or other official communication) - is it?

Comment: You're considering having a student removed from your class for asking a question about course policies?

Comment: Why do you find the student's attitude problematic?

Comment: Lots of strong reactions to this question; I've kept a few and [moved the rest to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138585/discussion-on-question-by-blade-student-keeps-asking-about-attendance-policy). Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230) before posting a comment below this one, and remember our [code of conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Since he asked about an attendance policy and you don’t have one, the appropriate way to reply would be to tell him “I don’t have an attendance policy.”

If he asks for clarification, you can say “that means that there is no requirement for you to attend the lectures.”

I don’t see what basis you have for wanting to tell him that your course “may not suit him”. That’s potentially an offensive and unfair thing to say to a student when your only reason for saying it is that he asked an administrative question about the course’s attendance policy.

If you think that the course might not suit people who don’t attend your lectures, well, it sounds like you might need an attendance policy after all, or at the very least a note in the syllabus expressing your strong belief in the importance of attending lectures. But jumping to the conclusion that the course might not suit someone merely for them *wanting to know what the attendance policy is* is uncharitable and, in my opinion, illogical.

Comment: Bear in mind that in some universities the research professors may have no teaching **obligation** yet may well see purpose in offering extra-curricular courses to MS students where such would be of use to those students' work and/or guide some of the students towards research in that RP's own group. Naturally, it is also healthy professional engagement for an RP and an opportunity at "voluntary" lecturing for those who may want to become established lecturers. Serious professionals need appreciation for their commitment from direct beneficiaries. Student's attitude doesn't show much of it.

Comment: @Trunk there is zero evidence in the question that the student has a bad attitude. Wanting to know about course policies (and asking again when the original answer is unclear) is 100% legitimate and not a sign of a bad attitude or of anything else. (And even a student with a not great attitude deserves to be treated fairly and not be the subject of hasty assumptions.)

Comment: I'm not saying OP's student *had* a bad attitude. But he really *showed* zero appreciation of OP's efforts by (thrice) baldly asking on attendance without any suggestion of why. I'm not saying either that OP's response was adequate - even if his feelings were hurt. It's just a case of OP getting used to the different interaction from research supervision when lecturing and the student getting used to being more of a colleague and less of a subordinate: soft skills aren't acquired on appointment for most of us. But OP wisely sought advice and didn't pull rank, took it on board and it's sorted.

Comment: @Trunk You made a correct guess that I had no obligation to offer a course, and did so to establish myself by teaching in the field of my research. And also that I sought advice before making a rookie mistake.

Comment: @Trunk you write that the student was, "baldly asking on attendance without any suggestion of why" without considering that it's truly none of the teacher's business. We are talking, quite literally, about what happens outside of the classroom. Just as teachers are not required to divulge personal details unrelated to the course, the student has no obligation and in fact should have a reasonable expectation of privacy.

Comment: @Trunk in the places I’m familiar with, students are not expected to show appreciation to university instructors when they ask administrative questions about course policies. There is also no expectation that they provide an explanation to the instructor about why they’re asking the question. So I honestly have no idea what you’re talking about.

Comment: @Trunk " student getting used to being more of a colleague and less of a subordinate" if you do not know the rules, like the attendance policy, because they are not clearly explained, you are at mercy of any person in charge, so you intrinsically become a subordinate.

Comment: @jonlink and Dan: Most departments' staff and students at most of the 6 places I attended were expected to show regard to the notion of working as a team in a multi-generational and multi-racial workplace. Sure, people fell down in this at times. But even lazy and corrupt HoDs I met recognized the need to maintain a façade at least of teamwork. Teamwork doesn't demand appreciation *to* anyone. But it does require appreciation *of* everyone's contribution - from the lab attendants to the HoD - to the whole functioning of the department. A bit of this from everyone avoids OP-type issues.

Comment: @EarlGrey  Yes. Of course. But wouldn't it be so much easier for the student to get the fuller answer he needs were he to preface the question with "Because of prior commitments I am not sure I can attend all scheduled course lectures . . ." ? A graduate student needs little coaching to appreciate the need to consider fellow graduate students. Staff-members cannot always be as forthright in their expressions of objection to the actions and manner of students - yet that isn't to say that they don't have feelings on the matter and such feelings deserve *some human consideration* by graduates.

Comment: Risking an interpretation of what the OP sees as problematic, I would add "there is no requirement for you to attend the lectures" *however* in my experience it is very difficult to achieve the course's objectives without attending, since it would require a lot of extra effort on the side of the student.

Comment: @Trunk There should be no need for the student to disclose *any* private issues to get an answer regarding a basic administrative question. Full stop. Making the requirements clear, especially when directly prompted, is a fundamental responsibility of any instructor.

Comment: @Neinstein  Research professors don't just provide lectures for lecturing practice. They also are an efficient way to get graduate students proficient with vital skills for their programs that are not core to their primary degree. For example, if OP had a research group on AI and his projects used Prolog or Lisp which few universities offer to undergrads. Such courses may be publicised within the university and get some grad students from other departments. They may also be publicised within the local region and attract paying attendees from industry - useful contacts for the research group.

Comment: @Neinstein  It's right that the student need not detail his reasons for occasional non-attendance. But a bland phrasing like "because of prior commitments" would be enough for most course lecturers. I think being strictly legalistic in the context of work-related communication is unwise as so many research staff are very focussed on their work and expect a good degree of focus from those around them. They tend to become hyper-efficient with time and will be watchful for wastage from newbees to their group. So, yes, **no detail** on why they can't attend. But a reference to "prior commitments".

Comment: @Trunk As someone who has to deal with lots of organizational questions in a business environment the idea that people have to  be grateful for me giving them answers seems weird - if I organize something I'm expected to provide that information, simple as that. Fostering an environment of "indulge personal information to get treated better" on the other hand would most certainly lead to a serious reprimand from HR - that's just not acceptable in any way, shape or form. Just to give you an idea how this would be treated outside the protected environment of a university.

Comment: @Voo  You make it sound like I want all grad students to kiss the asses off their professors. Come on, man. All I'd expect of grad students is that they consider the operation of the whole department and not just themselves. As a new PhD student I (presumably you too) had to be told this by the HoD after I didn't go to a seminar by a faculty member because the topic didn't interest me. PhD students can be very selfish. OP here perhaps misread his student's intention and initially presumed the wrong motive. But he still realized nobody has 360 perspective and sorted things out. So all's well.

Comment: @Trunk "initially presumed the wrong motive". That actually nicely sums up my problem: If your policy requires you to assume (and *judge*!) the motives of someone in a subordinate position, that should be a red flag. You could make the same argument about grading policies "I don't want to inform students about the grading policy, after all they should come to my class because they enjoy learning"

Comment: Of course. My intention throughout this has simply been to explain the genesis of the matter from the point of view of a *non-obligated* course provider who is a full-time research professor. I am *not* saying what OP did - initially - was right. Of course not. But he recovered. It's a big *modus operandi* jump from years in labs to the immediacy of the lecture theatre. Blade has to realize that class attendance is not just about interest in the topic: it's also predicated by the *manner* of content delivery. I think he will adapt as he's shown self-awareness and sought - and taken - advice.

Answer (score 96):

> I'm not too fond of the student's attitude, who keeps asking about the attendance policy four months in advance

I'd much rather a student ask about a policy in advance than after they've missed classes.

I would consider also that students in your course may have a lot of reasons to miss class that are not merely because they don't care about the course. They may be considering travel for conferences, and if they are undergraduates/masters students they may have graduate school/PhD interviews to schedule, which often interfere with ordinary coursework. They may have once-in-a-lifetime travel opportunities or important family obligations like a sibling's wedding. They may have a medical condition or ill child or parent and know they sometimes need to change their plans at the last minute to take care of those things. Your world might revolve around your course, but theirs does not and while they should make their courses a priority they need not make every course their *top* priority.

I would ask the student to clarify why they are asking about attendance in advance. I would guess that they have some known reasons that they may need to miss one or more classes, and are trying to plan ahead. I think it's fine to warn them that they may struggle if a class is missed, though I also think you should make at least a moderate effort to help them keep up, such as pointing them to reading material (you don't need to design a separate curriculum for them, just inform what will be covered). In some classes based on lab work or discussion, presence is absolutely necessary and you can certainly tell them this and let them make a decision based on that information.

Particularly for a graduate-level class, I would operate under the assumption that your students want to be there. These are the courses closest to their area of interest, not merely a necessary box to check to get a degree. I understand not wanting to be explicit about this sort of thing in the syllabus, but consider that this student is close to being a colleague of yours as a person educated in your field. It seems rude to me to refuse to answer their question or to answer by responding with a syllabus that lacks information about attendance expectations and leaving them to read your mind.

I think you should trust them with something similar to what you've written here: you don't think attendance policies are appropriate for a graduate course, your expectation is that students do everything possible to attend every class, and that they will miss out if they can't be present. If it were me, I would also ask if they are planning to miss certain classes and how many, and be honest about any way that will impact their grade. I think it's certainly reasonable to ask they do not take the course if they plan to miss an unacceptable number of sessions (and very reasonable for them to ask to find what this boundary is!).

Comment: In the current Covid climate, I've found that "need to miss one or more classes" translates into "I'm planning to live 250 miles from campus and never come to class."  Students who try this invariably end up in trouble even though there's no attendance grade.

Comment: @BrianBorchers That's quite possible, I think in that case it'll be clear what the student is after if they are asked to clarify.

Comment: I'll add that my experience of these "topics" style courses is that they're organized a lot like a "journal club", so the assessment may not be about exams or written papers (where a student who doesn't attend might struggle proportionately) but about presentation and discussion of papers (where being present is the whole point of the course), and if that's the case, OP should be clear about how this assessment will work even if they do not want to codify it as "you can only get an A if you attend X classes".

Comment: "I would ask the student to clarify why they are asking about attendance in advance."
If I were the student, I would prefer not to have someone with power over me (the professor) asking personal questions about problems I did not disclose beforehand.

Comment: @EarlGrey That question does not require a personal response beyond what the instructor needs to know.

Comment: @BryanKrause How would knowing the reason change anything?

Comment: @JSLavertu Perhaps OP would not be so concerned if they knew the student was asking because they had a known conflict with one or two of the class sessions. If they knew the student planned to miss half the class sessions, that would similarly guide their answer. I never said they need to know the reason for the *absence*, only the reason for asking about attendance policies, though it may be relevant as pertains to institution policies about absence types that require instructors to accommodate the student.

Comment: "They may be considering travel for conferences" after the edit, we know that this is exactly what happened

Comment: @BrianBorchers Even if that's the case, it has no relevance at all. There either is or isn't an attendance policy. In both cases, it is the student's, and not the teacher's, responsibility to decide whether or not they will attend. The teacher's responsibility is to make the rules and consequences obvious. No less, but no more. He has no business digging into the student's private reasons behind their decision.

Comment: @Neinstein I do not think finding out how many classes a student plans to miss or whether they will be absent for reasons protected by university policy are "digging into the student's private reasons". There is no need to treat a student exactly the same who is absent for reasons within versus outside their control.

Comment: @BryanKrause Two thing: a) there's already a bit of a mental jump in assuming a student will miss any classes for whatever reasons just from asking about attendance policy. b) If there is no attendance policy, the students are free to not attend for *any* reasons. A severe sickness is just as valid as their cat asking for more pets. If it was in any way not the case, there would be an attendance policy in effect by definition, which would include valid and invalid reasons, and require the student to prove the validity of their reasons, in whatever way.

Comment: @Neinstein Not sure it's such a jump, and in this case, my guess was totally right: the student was asking because they planned to miss two sessions and presumably wanted to know if this would impact their grade. If that's not the case, "I don't have any plans to miss class, but wanted to know what would happen if I do" is a fine answer. I think from the OP it was a bit unclear what the actual expectations are around attendance, because there is conflict between A) there is no attendance policy, and B) a student shouldn't take the class if they will be absent.

Comment: @Neinstein With respect to Brian's point about COVID and expectations around remote learning, I think it's very reasonable the instructor should be made aware if a student plans to live off-campus and not attend any sessions. For some courses designed around in-person interaction, this will simply not be an acceptable situation, and even if there is no policy around *attendance* per se, I would expect a student to fail a course if most of the grade is about those in-person discussions. "No attendance policy" does not mean "not attending class cannot affect the student's grade".

Comment: @BryanKrause I respect your points, but the student does not seem to ask whether "not attending class can affect the student's grade". He literally asked whether there is an attendance policy, and what is it; on which the clear and only answer is that there is none. Of course, not attending might *indirectly* influence the grades, but that's not what he asked. Also, lacking a policy, this is the *only* possible consequence of not attending. He could choose to never attend anything besides the tests without any negative discrimination (including being ejected from the class).

Comment: @Neinstein I think the student could have done a better job communicating in the first place by stating why they were asking about the policy, but I think it's also reasonable for the instructor here to guess that there is some information missing and ask about it. It's not necessary to be so strict and analytical here. If the instructor just said "there's no policy" and then the student never showed up for class but failed because they didn't get any points for class participation, I think the student would be quite upset.

Comment: (as I mentioned in another comment, often these "topics in X" graduate-level courses are more of an opportunity to present and talk about current research papers; there may not be any exams or formal assignments)

Comment: @BryanKrause I still maintain that that would be solely on the student, but I think it's a good time to agree to disagree. I agree there's no harm in doing some mentoring *while* answering the student's question, it's just that OP seemed to consider the absolute opposite of this.

Comment: _"It seems rude to me to refuse to answer their question or to answer by responding with a syllabus that lacks information about attendance expectations and leaving them to read your mind"_ This should be in bold. Uppercase. 2x font size.

Comment: There are many legitimate reasons for missing class, such as needing a part-time job to support themselves, if they are a carer for a family member, if they live far away and have transport difficulties. 
It seems presumptous to assume poor attendance means a disrespectful or a student with a poor attitude...

Answer (score 67):

Why all the negative judgment? Either you have an attendance policy or you don't. A grad student is an adult who can make his own decisions. If you expect people to attend and will penalize them if they don't, then you have an attendance policy and you should put it in the syllabus.

Answer (score 51):

**Don't remove them.** The student sounds great. They want to know what is expected.

The student explicitly asked about the attendance policy and instead of answering the question directly, you hinted it would be in the syllabus.

The syllabus was distributed with no mention of the attendance policy. Instead of apologizing for misleading them when asked again, you get annoyed. They have every right to know about the policy / lack of.

Leaving things vague seems like a lazy way of trying to cover yourself in case of problems.

Another reason to keep the student: The student hasn't complained. The student has every right to be frustrated with you for not including the information they requested in the syllabus you suggested it would be in. They waited almost four months for an answer for no reason.

I believe a short email from the start would have been the best way to go.

> "There is no strict attendance policy; however, if you expect to miss a lot of [activity], please speak to me by [date]."

Comment: That's actually a good policy to include in the syllabus. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

[Academia varies more than you think it does](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/academia-varies-more-than-you-think-it-does-the-movie). Policies -- and implicit norms -- regarding attendance (and much else) differ *widely* from university to university, country to country, department to department, and professor to professor. What may seem clear to you may seen quite unusual to another.

As such, my advice is to cheerfully and politely explain your expectations to any prospective student who asks.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't have an attendance policy, *you don't have an attendance policy.* **This is the answer to the student's question.**

Your reply email could consist of a mere six words. You are wasting your and the student's time by not answering a simple administrative question directly.

You can't have the cake and eat it. If you want to encourage attendance, then implement a soft or hard attendance policy in the syllabus. If you don't, don't try to make it look as if there is one.

*Besides, the student's question is very reasonable. The requirements for your course right now are unclear. Even considering kicking him out of the class seems like an overreaction.*

Answer (score 17):

I would not consider a syllabus to be complete without an attendance policy.  I think you should fix your syllabus.

I am not saying the policy needs to require you, or the students, to do anything.  The policy does need to set expectations.  For example:

> Students are expected to attend the scheduled course sessions.

Is a good policy because students know what you expect (attendance) and they know how attendance relates to their grade (not at all).

No policy at all is bad because some students have a history of success in classes they did not attend.  No policy sets expectations that your class is not worth attending.

Comment: "they know how attendance relates to their grade (not at all)" - it's not at all clear to me from the policy you've presented that non-attendance would have no affect on students' grades. On the contrary, expectations often come with consequences for not meeting them.

Answer (score 9):

After a certain age, it is in a students responsibility to know how they can learn and how they can't. If he asks, it might well be that he has big other plans that conflict with the lectures, like an internship or living with his girlfriend who lives in another country.

You should just answer the question as early as possible, in order for him to be able to make plans - "No, you don't need to be present in the lectures."

Answer (score 8):

Others mentioned that this might, or might not be, a student with a bad attitude and/or one that intends to skip your course.

Another possibility is that the student is being extra diligent or has a specific reason to ask. Many people with Autism function best when they are given highly detailed rules checklists and flowcharts rather than expected to rely on social nuances. If this is the case, providing explicit guidance on attendance is just a reasonable accommodation. Another possibility is that the student has had previous experience at an institution or with an instructor with a highly draconian attendance policy and is actually in fear of facing major negative consequences for minor attendance issues. The high school I attended as a child had a policy that any student with nine unexcused late arrivals during a quarter *automatically received a failing grade*. If you had passing, or even high, grades throughout the quarter but had already racked up eight late arrivals, you were right to be frightened as being even 30 seconds behind the bell would result in losing every one of those of those hard-earned points! If your student was previously at an institution like that, they may just need some reassurance that you will accept a reasonable good-faith effort and that you won't automatically flunk them for being 30 seconds behind the clock.

Answer (score 4):

I almost fell off my chair reading that you were going to remove a student for asking about attendance policy, that is really unfair to even think about. Lecturers don't usually come up with the policy, the university policy makers do that, so all you had to do was forward him to the correct department and it sounds like for 4 months you didn't do that. Unless you make something optional it falls under university policy usually.

Answer (score -1):

My wife taught at an institution where there was a mandatory attendance policy in place.  The history, so she was told, was that there was a trucking college that got in trouble with various government funding agencies because students were not really attending classes.  I've put that history here before and various people think it may not have really happened.

In any event, if your institution has a mandatory attendance policy, then implement one, because it is mandatory.  If it does NOT have such a policy, it is up to you.

When I was an undergrad, two of my co-students skipped 1/2 a certain class to attend another one that met at the same time.  The instructor didn't like this, but they did just fine as students.

Some lab courses, or courses with integral pars such as labs, have mandatory attendance, so the grading would flow from that.  [NOTE:  I re-worked this sentence based on a suggested edit, but with my own wording].

If you have a virtual option, it makes it easier to attend classes, especially as there may be a recording, but that was not available in my time as a student, nor really for the courses my wife was teaching in the late 1990's.

I tend to concur with the opinions registered that it would be too harsh to not allow the particular student in your class.

Best wishes on your journey.